# Print page in chrome table issues

Tags: html, google-chrome, printing

I have been attempting to resolve this issue to a while now. This issue is related to Chrome only. When I print page on a website I am working on the table cells span the whole row. So rather then having a table with 5 rows in the print page it displays each cell as 1 full width row. I have a print page css which I have tried to use to control the width of td and the table however it still drops each cell to a new row. Prints perfectly using FireFox. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this way:
where var data= $("#divtoprint").html();
  function ShowPrintWindowPopup(data) {
        var mywindow = window.open();
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
        mywindow.document.write('<style>');
        mywindow.document.write('table, th, td { border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black;width: 100%;text-align: left;border-spacing: 0;}');
        mywindow.document.write('a {color: #428bca;text-decoration: none;} ,table > tbody > tr {height:auto!important},table > thead > tr > th, table > tbody > tr > th, table > tfoot > tr > th, table > thead > tr > td, table > tbody > tr > td, table > tfoot > tr > td{vertical-align:top;padding:2px;font-size:8px;}');
        mywindow.document.write('table {border-collapse:collapse; table-layout:fixed;} , table td {border:solid 1px #fab; word-wrap:break-word; -ms-word-break: break-all; word-break: break-all; word-break: break-word;-webkit-hyphens: auto;-moz-hyphens: auto;-ms-hyphens: auto;hyphens: auto;}')
        mywindow.document.write('</style>');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body style="direction:ltr;font-size:10px;">');
        mywindow.document.write('<div style="text-align:center;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;">title</div><br />');
        mywindow.document.write('<br/><br/>');
        mywindow.document.write(data);
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        mywindow.document.close();
        mywindow.print();
        return true;


    }
```